# WPF MVVM Datagrid Two Way Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have List<object> and DataGrid bound to it with IPropertyChanged interface. I would like that changes in DataRowCells are reflected in object properties. I have also implemented CheckBox in DataGrid and Textbox and i would like that text from TextBox update specific column cells of all selected (checked) rows. So I must change one cell of each selected row based on one TextBox, and that change should be saved in bound object. For example I want that for all selected rows cell SUPPLIER_ID take value of TextBox text, and that value should be reflected in bound objects prop SUPPLIER_ID

My Collection in ViewModel:

```
private List<Article> articlesFalseCatalogGroup;

    public List<Article> ArticlesFalseCatalogGroup
    {
        get { return articlesFalseCatalogGroup; }
        set
        {
            articlesFalseCatalogGroup = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ArticlesFalseCatalogGroup");
        }
    }
```

This is one prop from object:

```
public class Article: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }

    #region Standard fields

    private string _SUPPLIER_AID;

    public string SUPPLIER_AID
    {
        get { return _SUPPLIER_AID; }
        set
        {
            _SUPPLIER_AID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SUPPLIER_AID");
        }
    }
```

XAML DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ArticlesFalseCatalogGroup, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" IsThreeState="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column definition with two-way binding:

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SUPPLIER_AID, Mode=TwoWay"} Header="SUPPLIER_AID" />
```